# Why does my Macbook Pro have such a hard time finding my Canon MG5520?

Tags: macos, printing, printer, macbook-pro, canon-pixma

I have a 2012 MacBook Pro, and I have a Canon MG5520 (its one of those pixma models). I have it one my network, and I never have a problem printing from my iPhone, iPad,A Android, PC, etc. Only my MBP. It works one time and then the next it cant find the printer. Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Are you using the official drivers? Or are you just letting the Mac figure it out by itself?

Comment: Always official :)

Comment: Try uninstalling the drivers. The Mac should be able to pick up the printer automatically and this should tell you if it's a driver level issue or not.

Comment: I tried that, and it picks up the printer just fine. I can configure it and everything, just cant print. Im thinking maybe its an issue with my network setup. If I restart my MBP it prints just fine for a few days. Maybe having trouble connecting to the printer when DHCP assigns the printer a new IP?

Comment: Also worth noting that apparently the drivers do not yet officially support OS X Mavericks...

Answer (score 0):

What I did was make sure when I set up the printer, that I choose the one with the MAC address in the name. This is what finally fixed the issue for me....for now.